# Get Embed html code for bing map based on dynamic address

Tags: bing-api, bing-maps

How to get the Bing maps embed html code based on dynamic address. In my page i have a city and state based on the i need to show the embed map in a page.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details? Usually when you want to do anything more than show a map for a single location you would use the Bing Maps API's and not the embedded map API (which is old and will likely be turned off at some point).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a form where i get address details like street,state country and all and i want to show a embeded map in a end user page. Please let me know how to get this done

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you will have several options including embedded maps, using interactive controls or even static imagery service.

**Embedded Maps:**

Based on your feedback, the simplest way to achieve what you want to do is for you to use the embedded maps, you will find options on the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692180.aspx

You can also think at using the Bing Maps website and configure the behavior of the portal using extra parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx

**Static imagery map**

If you just want to display a static map (image) with a pushpin at the specific location, see the REST Imagery service here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Sample url: http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road/Bellevue%20Washington?mapLayer=TrafficFlow&key=BingMapsKey

**Interactive map using AJAX v7**

You can find everything you need to implement your own interactive map using JavaScript on your page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx